# @Published for a computed property (or best workaround)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to build an app with SwiftUI, and I'm just getting started with Combine framework. My first simple problem is that I'd like a single variable that defines when the app has been properly initialized. I'd *like* it to be driven by some nested objects, though. For example, the app is initialized when the account object is initialized, the project object is initialized, etc. My app could then use GlobalAppState.isInitialized, instead of inspected each nested object.

```
class GlobalAppState: ObservableObject {

    @Published var account: Account = Account()
    @Published var project: Project = Project()

    @Published var isInitialized: Bool {
        return self.account.initialized && self.project.initialized;
    }
}
```

I get the error `Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property`

So...clearly, this is currently disallowed. Is there a way I can work around this??? I'd like to be able to use `GlobalAppState.initialized` as a flag in the app. More to the point, something like `GlobalAppState.project.currentProject`, which would be a computed property returning the currently selected project, etc...

I can see this pattern being used in a thousand different places! Any help would be wildly appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case there's no reason to use `@Published` for the `isInialized` property since it's derived from two other Published properties.

```
    var isInitialized: Bool {
        return self.account.initialized && self.project.initialized;
    }
```

Comment: I am both happy and annoyed that the answer is so simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: So if we were just observing `isInitialized` from SwiftUI, would it automatically update if `account` or `project` changed?

Comment: @lewis afaik, in SwiftUI you observe objects, not properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one case if both `account` and `project` are structures.

```
       struct Account{
            var initialized : Bool = false
        }

        struct Project{
            var initialized : Bool = false
        }

        class GlobalAppState: ObservableObject {

            @Published var account: Account = Account()
            @Published var project: Project = Project()
            @Published var isInitialized: Bool = false

             var cancellabel: AnyCancellable?

            init(){
                cancellabel =  Publishers.CombineLatest($account, $project).receive(on: RunLoop.main).map{
                           return ($0.0.initialized &&  $0.1.initialized)
                           }.eraseToAnyPublisher().assign(to: \GlobalAppState.isInitialized, on: self) as AnyCancellable
                }


        }


        struct GlobalAppStateView: View {

        @ObservedObject var globalAppState = GlobalAppState()

        var body: some View {
            Group{
              Text(String(globalAppState.isInitialized))
              Button(action: { self.globalAppState.account.initialized.toggle()}){ Text("toggle Account init")}
              Button(action: { self.globalAppState.project.initialized.toggle()}){Text("toggle Project init")}
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you - there are some ideas in here i still have to fully understand, so i will come back to this to study it some more - thanks so much for your time!

Comment: isInitialized should be a computed property, i.e. only a getter. You have a property that has a setter.